# Setter TargetName 'ContentPresenter' not recognized in Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a ContentPresenter and the Opacity of the Content should become 0.5 when the Button is disabled, but the Setter cant find it by TargetName. Is there something I am missing?

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="MenuButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Margin="1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Opacity="1.0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>

        </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ControlTemplate.Triggers` to change `ContentPresenter` properties via Setters. "ContentPresenter" name is known only in template.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="MenuButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Margin="1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Opacity="1.0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For such issues, you need to understand the concept of `NameScope`. `Template` define its own `NameScope`. So, your `TargetName` won't work from outside the template.

So, try to access it from inside `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks Ive never heard that this is it's own namescope, neither have heard of it. I guess I've watched/read some bad Tutorials, haha. Thanks for explaining.